# KeyError: 'val_accuracy'

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

После обучения нейронной сети получаю ошибку:

> KeyError:'val_accuracy'.

Изначально, использовал библиотеки из *keras* и *tenseflow*. Консоль выдавала информацию по четырем значениям: `accuracy, val_accuracy, loss, val_loss`.

После я изменил все библиотеки по примеру `from tensorflow.keras`. Значения `val_accuracy, val_loss` исчезли и появилась ошибка:

> KeyError: 'val_accuracy'

в строке:

```
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
```

Как исправить ошибку и сделать так, чтобы консоль выдвала необходимые метрики при обучении?

Библиотеки:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

Резюме модели:

```
#Resume of the model
model.summary()

opt = Adam(learning_rate=LR, decay=LR / EPOCHS)
# distribution
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
# train the network
print("[INFO] обучение сети...")
history = model.fit(augment.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                              validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                              steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BATCH_SIZE,
                              epochs=EPOCHS, 
                              verbose=1)
```

Построение графиков:

```
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)

#Train and validation accuracy
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Точность на обучении')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Точность на валидации')
plt.title('Точность на обучающих и валидационных данных')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()

#Train and validation loss
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'b', label='Потери на обучении')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Потери на валидации')
plt.title('Потери на обучающих и валидационных данных')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Так вы напечатайте перед этим `print(history.history)` и посмотрите, что там вообще есть, какие ключи. Я так понимаю, это словарь, при печати выйдут ключи, которые есть в словаре.

Comment: Поддерживаю вышестоящий коммент. Только я бы напечатал через **.items()**, чтобы каждый ключ в строке был - так понятнее будет

Comment: только тогда надо через звездочку и sep="\n" добавить

Comment: @alex Да пусть хоть что-нибудь уже напечатает

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответы. Помогла переустановка python и всех библиотек. Видимо, ошибка связана с конфликтом некоторых библиотек. До того как она появилась, я пытался установить CUDA и cudnn, для этого понизил версию tf с 2.7 до 2.6.

Comment: Ну вы зря всё-таки не попробовали напечатать тот словарь, возможно там были нужные значения, просто в другой версии библиотек они назывались чуть по-другому. Хотя, конечно, если удалось запустить свежие версии, то это лучше, чем приспособиться к старым версиям.